# React app deployed on Heroku gives 404. Using json-server and express

Tags: reactjs, express, heroku, json-server

I am using json-server alongside express to create a mock database. The app works correctly when the base url and the api endpoints are hit but when any other url is hit Heroku returns 404. So for example if https://invoice-app-88.herokuapp.com/something is hit then Heroku returns 404 and app.get('*') will not put me back to the static index.html.

The base url is https://invoice-app-88.herokuapp.com/

The api endpoints are
https://invoice-app-88.herokuapp.com/invoices

and

https://invoice-app-88.herokuapp.com/invoices:id

This is my server.js file containing my express and json-server code

```
const jsonServer = require("json-server");
const path = require("path");
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const router = jsonServer.router("db.json");
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.use("/", express.static("build"), router);

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  app.get("*", function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname + "./build/index.html"));
  });
}

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server started on PORT ${PORT}`));
```

EDIT: Made edit for clarification of issue.

Comment: What url is hit Heroku returns 404?

Comment: This is the base url [https://invoice-app-88.herokuapp.com/](https://invoice-app-88.herokuapp.com) that returns fine. The api endpoints are [https://invoice-app-88.herokuapp.com/invoices]https://invoice-app-88.herokuapp.com/invoices and [https://invoice-app-88.herokuapp.com/invoices/:id]https://invoice-app-88.herokuapp.com/invoices/:id. When i use the url https://invoice-app-88.herokuapp.com/something-else Heroku returns 404.